# Easiest way to replicate local web development environment (Python, Flask, SQL) with web provider?

Tags: python, docker, web, flask, cloud

I'm building a website using the following stack:

- Python
- Flask
- mariadb / postgresql
- some web server - apache, whatever

Ideally, I'd like the ability to have the local developer environment exactly replicated as it's deployed to a remote web / cloud provider. I would like to learn as close to nothing as possible about this provider.

For example, I could use containers for this (but I'm not married to containers). I'd have 1 container for the web server, 1 for the app, 1 for the DB, and then issue 1 command to deploy those containers remotely and viola - a web page.

Any ideas? I've briefly looked at Heroku and Digital Ocean. Any others I'm missing? Is there a tutorial anyone could point me to that matches what I'm looking for?

I suppose I could always spin up a VM somewhere then use an ansible playbook to push the container images remotely but I'd like to avoid maintaining a VM. So, on one hand something that does everything for me, on the other I'd like to learn close to nothing about their platform.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend reversing the problem. Use local Virtual Machines to set up a local development environment that matches the deployment environment. VirtualBox and Vagrant are a powerful combination for this. A 2Gb VM can run a Flask app behind nginx using uwsgi, plus MariaDB, plus Redis, and still have some headroom left. I've cranked VMs down to 1Gb to mimic a Rasperry Pi, and it's been fine.

Chapter 17 of the [Flask Mega Tutorial](https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-xvii-deployment-on-linux) covers enough of the setup to get you started.

Comment: That's definitely an option. It should also be possible to use the vagrant CLI to push the VM to a cloud provider and update production that way.

The alternative would be to create containers in the local dev env, and use AWS / Azure / Google clouds to run those containers directly.